# How to pass object in :with field for a link_to_remote call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an object elem that I'd like to pass to the remove_tag_from_cart method.
Here is my attempt:

```
-counter.times do |c|
  -elem = @tags[c]
  #{elem.name}#{link_to_remote image_tag('x.png'), :url => {:controller => 'questions', :action => 'remove_tag_from_cart'}, :with => {:tag_to_remove => :elem}}
```

The `:with` clause isn't working correctly. The image does not even show up. If I take out the `:with` clause, then the link properly shows up and calls the method correctly, but I need the `elem` object in order to remove it from the `cart`.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M002174)

**:with:    A JavaScript expression specifying the parameters for the XMLHttpRequest. Any expressions should return a valid URL query string.**

Example:

Try

```
:with =>"'tag_remove=' + #{elem}"
```